# Find $7$ integers with certain guidelines.

Tags: combinatorics

I am unable to solve this problem. I will be positing my thoughts on how to solve this problem as well. All help is appreciated, though I'm mainly looking for a method and proper answer!

$1$. Let $g(x)$ define the set of $7$ distinct positive integers such that for all $1\leq{x}\leq7$, the arithmetic mean of any $x$ distinct elements (of $g(x)$) is an integer. Let $n$ be the minimum possible value of the sum of the elements of $g(x)$. Find the remainder when $n$ is divided by $1000$.

$\textbf{Thoughts}$: Let there be $7$ integers $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $...$, $x_7$.

For any sum of two elements, the sum needs to be even.

For any sum of three elements, the sum needs to be divisible by $3$.

For any sum of four elements, the sum needs to be divisible by $4$.

We can keep doing this until we have defined our guidelines for set $g(x)$.

Since we have $7$ terms and we want to choose $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, etc to realize if the sum is divisible by $x$. I think that the answer would be $\binom{7}{1}$+$\binom{7}{2}$+$\binom{7}{3}$...+$\binom{7}{7}$. This gives us $128$, which is obviously $\textbf{not the right answer}$.

Comment: You have five entirely different questions here - you'll get better answers if they're each posted separately.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I'm new to math.stachexchange, so I didn't know what is right or is not right...should I just edit all of them?

Comment: What is $x$ in $g(x)$? Are you not looking for a single set, which for the sake of argument we could call $g$?

Answer (score 3):

### Hint:

Suppose that the numbers are $x_i,x_2,\ldots,x_7$ and consider any two $i\not=j$ and any $2\leq m\leq6$. Then consider a subset of size $m$ containing $x_i$ but not $x_j$, and the same subset of size $m$ except with $x_i$ swapped for $x_j$. Assume the sum of the elements that are not $x_i$ is $k$. Then $m|k+x_i,k+x_j$ so $x_i\equiv x_j\mod m$ for all $i,j$ and $2\leq m\leq6$.

Now how do we find the smallest ones that work?

### Answer:

> The lcm of $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is $60$ so the numbers are all multiples of $60$ apart. Therefore the smallest they can be is $1,61,121,181,\ldots,361$ with sum $1267$ which is divisble by $7$. So your answer would be $267$